# should i always include else in my if statement?

Tags: c#-4.0

I am getting an error message "not all code paths return a value". Can anybody tell me what I missed?

```
    public string AddLineBreak(string str, int column)
    {
        if (str == null || str.Length == 0)
           return "";
    }
```

Comment: unrelated to question, but is to your code: .NET has an inbuilt function for testing if a string is null or has no content https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Your method `AddLineBreak` does not add a line break.  Or do anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed what happens if the `if` isn't true.

```
public string AddLineBreak(string str, int column)
{
    if (str == null || str.Length == 0)
       return "";
    // What happens if str != null or str.Length != 0?
}
```

In this case, you can resolve it with a simple `return` (presuming you know what you want to return, that is):

```
public string AddLineBreak(string str, int column)
{
    if (str == null || str.Length == 0)
       return "";
    return WhatEver_AddLineBreak_Using_str_and_column_returns;
}
```